# __all__ equivalent for `import modulename`

Tags: python

I made a [package](https://github.com/toto112358/base-converter).
My code is organized as follow:

```
sh-5.1$ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── baseXtoY
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── modules
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── number.py
├── dist
│   ├── baseXtoY-0.4-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── baseXtoY-0.4.tar.gz
└── setup.py

3 directories, 9 files
sh-5.1$ more baseXtoY/__init__.py 
from .modules import baseXtoY, license
__all__ = ['baseXtoY', 'license']
sh-5.1$
```

## issue

When I import:

```
>>> import baseXtoY
>>> dir(baseXtoY)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'baseXtoY', 'license', 'modules']
```

There is a module `baseXtoY.modules`.

--> *How can I prevent this type of behavior,
if it is even possible?*

Comment: Why do you feel you need to prevent this?

Comment: Curiosity.  After thinking about it, it is not necessary.  However, an user who writes `baseXtoY.` in python interpreter and then TAB will see the `modules` suggestion appear. If I created more folders this could get kind of confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any fix is going to require rearranging your package contents. But that might be OK, since it seems like the `modules` subpackage is not part of the main package's public API (or you wouldn't be trying to hide it from view).

One fix would be to do away with `modules` entirely, and either move the modules it contains into the main package, or inline the code they contain into other existing modules in the main package. That's obviously going to be a fairly broad and disruptive change to your whole package's organization, so it may not be practical, but it would keep `modules` out of the `dir` entry for the package by virtue of it not existing at all!

A more modest fix would be to write a `__dir__` function at the top level of your `baseXtoY/__init__.py` file. It should return a sequence containing the names of the attributes you want to see `dir` return when it is called on your package. This would definitely solve your immediate issue, but it might make coding and debugging things more complicated later, as you'll need to keep the list updated, and you won't be able to easily get the default `dir` results to see what attributes are being defined in the module's global namespace (though you can still find the names and values manually by reading the package's `__dict__`).

A third option might be to rename the `modules` subpackage to `_modules`. Names with a leading underscore will still be included in `dir`'s output by default, but the leading underscore suggests that they're private implementation details, not an official part of an API (unless there is documentation saying otherwise some where else).

The final option is of course to do nothing, and just live with the fact that `dir` leaks some implementation details to your users. They're going to have the package's files anyway, if they want to investigate the internals of your package, they'll be able to find the details regardless of what `dir` tells them. Write good documentation for the public API of your module, and let anyone who messes with the undocumented stuff do their own debugging.

Comment: I will rename modules to _modules I think.  I might validate your answer.  By the way, how did you get so much reputation?  You're insane!!!  Impressive!

Comment: writing a __dir__ function doesn't work

Comment: Issue fixed.  I just renamed modules to _main.  It worked.  Maybe if I renamed it to _modules it would have done the same, however _main was more coherent.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, `__dir__` worked for me though I didn't fully recreate your nested package situation, maybe some part of that bypasses it... As for how to get 80k+ rep, most of that is just giving lots of answers over nearly 9 years. A few people get huge rep for one or questions or answers that go viral, but mostly it's just time and lots of content getting a few votes each.

Comment: can you show me your dir function?  Or did you create a class and the used a super() to edit the __dir__

Comment: For my test module I used `def __dir__(): return []`, you'll probably want something that actually includes some names in the list. Maybe `return __all__` could work?

Comment: I'll try, but I won't include this in my module I think.  By the way, I started a rewrite of the overloading module if you want to check out?  It's OverloadingFixed on pypi